# Trigonometry help

Tags: trigonometry

Taking online classes and trying to find the angle in degrees of csc when given a decimal

Example in text not helping

Question is 
csc (theta) = 1.245 and they want an angle in degrees

Thank you in advance 
Lisa

Comment: Calculator is allowed?

Comment: Yes  using a calculator is how I found sin cos and tan angles in other questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all calculators are programmed with just the sine function ($\sin$), the cosine function ($\cos$), and the tangent function ($\tan$). To work with the secant, cosecant and cotangent functions, we need to use some trig identities and some algebra.

Your problem asks us to solve for $\theta$ where $\csc\theta=1.245$.

We know that $\csc\theta=\frac{1}{\sin\theta}$. Using this identity, we solve for $\theta$.

\begin{align}
\csc\theta&=1.245\\
\frac{1}{\sin\theta}&=1.245\\
\frac{1}{1.245}&=\sin\theta\\
\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{1.245}&=\theta
\end{align}

Remember that $\sin^{-1}$ is the inverse sine, also denoted as $\arcsin$. Using the calculator, we find that $\sin^{-1}(1/1.245)=53.44^{\circ}\text{ or }0.933\text{ radians}$.

Comment: THANK YOU !!!!! That makes total sense now and examples in text are not similar at all ! Can this example be used for cot and sec too.    I really appreciate the help

Comment: Yes, you can use the same method for $\sec$ and $\cot$. If you are happy with this solution, please mark it as your accepted solution.

Comment: Sorry. Total newby. On my iPhone.  Couldn't sleep til I figured it out or got the answer :) where do I mark an accepted solution :) thanks. Is it the green check mark :)

Comment: Looks like you marked the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you and to everyone who helped :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is take the inverse function to return the original angle. 
We know that $\csc (\theta)= 1.256$, so solving for $\theta$

$\csc^{-1}(\theta)=\csc^{-1}(1.245)=\ \approx53.44$ degrees

Comment: Sorry it was 1.245. But would you use csc or sin?   I did sin and answer was wrong.

Comment: Notice that the cosecant function is defined as $\frac{1}{\sin}$. Because the problem references cosecant and not sine, you would want to use inverse cosecant and **not** inverse sine.

Comment: Just checked calculator has no csc function. I'll need to buy a new calculator    Thank you very much.

Comment: You won't have to. Just use the "$\sin$" button, and then put $1$ over your answer or raise it to the $-1$ power, whichever is easier.

Comment: So I could do 1 / sin 1.245

Comment: Yes! In fact you can use this for the trigonometric ratios sine, cosine, and tangent. For cosecant $(\csc)$, use $\frac{1}{\sin}$, for secant($\sec$), use $\frac{1}{\cos}$ and for cotangent ($\cot$) use $\frac{1}{\tan}$